# Jquery Paypal form and shopping cart synchronisation and updation and add and remove products to cart

Tags: jquery, forms, paypal, shopping-cart, dynamic-data

So im trying to synchronise my cart and my hidden paypal form and im struglging to get this right.

When i add items to my cart jquery updates the cart by adding a row to my table and inserting a row to my paypal form.

*example of cart table:*

```
<td>
<td style="width: 70%">product 1</td>
<td style="width: 15%">£1.99</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
    <a class="del" href="#" data-rowid="row_id_1">X</a>
</td>
<td>
<td style="width: 70%">product 4</td>
<td style="width: 15%">£1.99</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
    <a class="del" href="#" data-rowid="row_id_4">X</a>
</td>
```

but when i remove an item it leaves my paypal form out of sych, for example see *paypal form below*

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypaltest@me.co.uk ">
<input class="row_id_1" type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="product 1">
<input class="row_id_1" type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.99">
<input class="row_id_1" type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1">
<input class="row_id_4" type="hidden" name="item_name_4" value="product 4">
<input class="row_id_4" type="hidden" name="amount_4" value="2.99">
<input class="row_id_4" type="hidden" name="item_number_4" value="1">
```

Paypal wont accept the above because row_id_2 & row_id_3 are missing. whats the best way to loop through these and synchronise? would **.load()** the form be a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer to this. But I was and came across your question. After a fruitless search for an answer I wrote  this...

```
// REFACTOR PAYPAL FORM BASED ON ITEM BEING REMOVED
function refactorPaypalForm(keyPosition){
    var refactorValue = keyPosition+1;
    var newValue = keyPosition;

    while( $("#item_name_"+refactorValue).length ){
        $("#item_name_"+refactorValue).attr("name", "item_name_"+newValue).attr("id", "item_name_"+newValue);
        $("#amount_"+refactorValue).attr("name", "amount_"+newValue).attr("id", "amount_"+newValue);
        newValue = refactorValue;
        refactorValue++;
    }

}
```

This seems to work if you call the function and pass in the 'key' value you are removing (i.e. pass in a 3 and it will remove item_name_3 and then rename _4 to _3 and _5 to _4 etc). You'll need to give your form elements an id of "item_name_x" and "amount_x" though for it to work in its present form but I'm sure you can adjust it to suit just the name. :-)